# Luarocks upload - "Error: file not found"

Tags: lua, luarocks

I'm trying to use `luarocks` to upload a project. However, when I run

```
$ luarocks upload kong-plugin-hello-0.1.0-1.rockspec --api-key=<REDACTED>
```

It returns `Error: File not found: git:github.com/JoshTheGoldfish/kong-plugin-hello`

Below is my rockspec:

```
package = "kong-plugin-hello"
version = "0.1.0-1"

local pluginName = package:match("^kong%-plugin%-(.+)$")  -- "myPlugin"

supported_platforms = {"linux", "macosx"}

source = {
   url = "git:github.com/JoshTheGoldfish/kong-plugin-hello",
   tag = "v0.1.0",
}

description = {
  summary = "Kong is a scalable and customizable API Management Layer built on top of Nginx.",
  homepage = "http://getkong.org",
  license = "Apache 2.0"
}

dependencies = {
}

build = {
  type = "builtin",
  modules = {
    ["kong.plugins."..pluginName..".handler"] = "kong/plugins/"..pluginName.."/handler.lua",
    ["kong.plugins."..pluginName..".schema"] = "kong/plugins/"..pluginName.."/schema.lua",
  }
}
```

Any my code can be found here: https://github.com/JoshTheGoldfish/kong-plugin-hello

Any clue what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`source.url` needed to be: `git://github.com...` not `git:github.com...`